# Error message when importing obj file

Tags: import, obj

I try to import on .obj File and this error message pops up.
When I try to import another obj exported file from the same program it works.
Can someone pls tell  me what is wrong with the file / or blender?

[image]

Comment: Looks like an error from the program which created your Obj file rather than from Blender or it could be a corrupt Obj file. Can you create or download it again and try again?

Comment: Already created it a couple of times and it gives me the error message every time

Comment: Might be worth updating to the latest Blender version (3.2.2) and then reporting it as a bug via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu if it's still happening.